# Why does a downloaded spreadsheet not automatically calculate?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel spreadsheet that was created using Office 2016 and the sheet that I created has formulas that reference blank cells. This sheet, which can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1caAJCtpIUqqAhFPN0Pcjuev0-rmRVXcV), is set to automatically calculate in the TOTAL COST column (column I) and a TOTAL SUM of all TOTAL COSTS in cell I54. When I created this sheet on my computer, it worked flawlessly; however, when I email it or upload it to our website for potential vendors to download and fill, it does not automatically calculate in any of the locations. My questions are:

1. Why does it work on my desktop and not on other people's systems? and
2. How do I correct this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: IIRC if it's downloaded, you have to allow Excel to run the calculations/formulas within the file on open.

Comment: Thanks, BruceWayne, but how do I do that? Also, I wasn't able to attach the sheet so I added a link to where it can be downloaded. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic recalculation must be enabled in Excel (on the computers where is doesn't happen). Mostly likely it works for you but is disabled on your partner's computer.

To recalculate all dependent formulas every time you make a change to a value, formula, or name, go to *File > Options > Formulas*. In the Calculation options section, under Workbook Calculation, click **Automatic**. This is the default calculation setting.

To recalculate all dependent formulas — except data tables — every time you make a change to a value, formula, or name, in the Calculation options section, under Workbook Calculation, click **Automatic except for data tables**.

[image]